# Pointer casts for itk::SmartPointer?

Tags: c++, casting, smart-pointers, reference-counting, itk

I'm looking for something like `std::static_pointer_cast`, `std::const_pointer_cast`, and `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` for `std::shared_pointer`.

I tried ITK's documentation and `itk::SmartPointer`'s source code and found nothing about smart pointer casting.

In one particular case I needed to add 'constness' to a pointer (convert `itk::SmartPointer<T>` to `itk::SmartPointer<const T>`) in order to pass it to a third-party function. Passing a raw pointer is out of the question because data will be deleted once the automatically created const smart pointer goes out of scope.

The only relatively safe solution I found:

`static_cast<itk::SmartPointer<const T>>(itk_smart_pointer_of_t)`.

I don't know whether this approach is thread-safe or has other possible pitfalls. Moreover, in case of `dynamic_cast` things will get even messier.

It seems strange that ITK doesn't have native `std::const_pointer_cast`-like and other casts.

Comment: And what have you found? What have you tried? What are you going to do with those things? And how do they relate to ITK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**: `itk::SmartPointer` doesn't need pointer casts, just cast the "raw" pointer and re-wrap it instead.

---

ITK smart pointers use intrusive reference counting, meaning that the owned object must provide the reference counter.

`itk::SmartPointer` can only be used with ITK classes, or, more accurately, with classes which have `Register()` and `UnRegister()` methods. For example, descendants of `itk::LightObject` class which, according to documentation,

> is the highest level base class for most itk objects. It implements reference counting ...

Therefore, my assumption that

> Passing a raw pointer is out of the question because data will be deleted once the automatically created const smart pointer goes out of scope.

is incorrect, because temporary `itk::SmartPointer` will just increase and then decrease owned object's reference counter.

This means it is safe to pass a "not-so-raw" pointer to a function accepting a smart pointer, or to create temporary smart pointer manually and pass it to the function.